# Probabilty of thesis veracity based on multiple experiments

Tags: probability

(**To long to read**:
Experiment $A$ proves that a thesis $\theta$ is true with probabilty (confidence level) of $P(A)$. Given confidence levels from independent experiments $A, B, C,\dots$ what's the probability that the thesis $\theta$ is indeed true?)

Hi All,

Imagine you're a researcher responsible for finding a bone marrow donor for *Jack* who needs a transplantation. You're using method $A$ to assess the probability of compatibility between *Jack* and the group of potential donors. Finally, you find *Ellen*, for whom the method $A$ indicates there is a probability $P(A)$ of compatibility between *Jack* and *Ellen*.

The probability $P(A)$ is high enough to attract your attention, but still the $1 - P(A)$ cannot be neglected. You don't want to commit an error which would have fatal consequences, so you use other methods $B$ and $C$ to assess the compatibility between *Jack* and *Ellen*. The result of the experiments are $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ respectively.

Given the confidence levels $P(A), P(B), P(C), \dots$ what are the chances that *Jack* and *Ellen* are indeed compatible?

Let's assume that all the methods are equally valid and their results are correct and unquestionable.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say just from the information you mention.

For example, if $80\%$ of the population is compatible with Jack and all three tests yield probabilities of $80\%$, then the tests haven't actually generated any new information, and your overall belief in Ellen's compatibility should still be $80\%$.

On the other hand, if $10\%$ of the population is compatible with Jack and all three tests yield probabilities of $80\%$, then under suitable independence assumptions for the tests your overall belief in Ellen's compatibility should now be much higher than $80\%$.

Comment: Hi joriki, thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: What if we don't know the percent of population compatible with Jack?

(I reckon that if we knew, that would mean we already checked how many of the population are compatible with Jack and we presumably wouldn't have to be searching)


What if instead we assume the result $P(A)$ is absolute? For example, that from the group of people who "scored" 80%, **in reality** only 80% are compatible?


Does this approach make sense to you?

Comment: @Ismael: If I understand correctly, you want to fix the indeterminacy in the original problem statement by adding the assumption that the probabilities $P(A)$ etc. are "absolute". I thought a bit about what exactly you might mean by that, but I found myself speculating and decided that a more efficient next step would be for you to define what you mean by that. If you can't give a formal definition, perhaps describe a concrete example of such a test that would clarify in what sense the probabilities are to be viewed as "absolute".

Comment: @Ismael: The mere fact that of the people who scored $80\%$, $80\%$ are indeed compatible, merely confirms that we're entitled to call these numbers probabilities in the first place – it tells us nothing about their interdependence. In particular, this would also be the case in the scenario that I described in my answer, which, if I understand correctly, is not one in which you view the probabilities as "absolute".

Comment: Hey @joriki. Yes, let me try to explain. What I'm trying to understand by this question in general is how can we deal with a situation when we are given a set of "clues" whether $A$ has property $x$ or $y$ and want to assess our "best bet". Especially if the clues are imposed and we can't question them, but we can safely assume they are correct.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase the problem with this example:
Your father has a herd of sheep. He knows the herd very well, but you don't because you have always been more interested in mathematics rather than herding cattle. One day your father tells you that 80% of the black sheep in the herd are male and that exactly 40% of the lambs are male. He locked a sheep in your room (surprise!) and asks you to guess whether it's male or female, giving you the only clue that it's a black lamb. If you lose you will have to clean the sheep's pen of poo. What would be your "safest bet" in such situation?

Comment: @Ismael: Great, thanks for the example. It may serve well to illustrate some of the points here. There's no way to answer this question without more information. My father knows that I spent a lot of time on math, so he might expect me to apply math to it, and his best strategy might be to choose a lamb of the opposite sex to what a mathematical analysis might suggest to be more probable. So we need information on how my father chose the sheep. Perhaps you meant to imply that he chose it randomly, but even that isn't enough. Randomly according to what distribution?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to imply a uniform distribution – but even that isn't enough. Uniform among which population? Did he uniformly randomly choose one of the sheep, and it happened to be a black lamb? Or did he uniformly randomly choose one of the black lambs? If the latter, we would again have to consider his rationale for doing so -- perhaps because he knows that among the black lambs there are fewer sheep of the sex that I'm likely to guess.

Comment: Perhaps you think that all this doesn't matter because we know "absolute" probabilities. But that's also not true. For all we know, there might be just a single black lamb, of either sex, and my father could have chosen it to fool me. So I'm afraid you'll have to specify a lot more for the question to be meaningful.

Comment: @Ismael: To state the insuffiency of the information more formally, in terms of [conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability): You're looking for

$$
P(\text{male}\mid\text{black}\land\text{lamb})=\frac{P(\text{male}\land\text{black}\land\text{lamb})}{P(\text{black}\land\text{lamb})}
$$

and you're given

$$
P(\text{male}\mid\text{black})=\frac{P(\text{male}\land\text{black})}{P(\text{black})}
$$

and

$$
P(\text{male}\mid\text{lamb})=\frac{P(\text{male}\land\text{lamb})}{P(\text{lamb})}\;.
$$

Comment: @Ismael: Note the complete lack of overlap between the quantities appearing in the expression for the desired probability and the quantities appearing in the expressions for the given probabilities. You need to make additional assumptions, e.g. independence assumptions, to connect the two. In other problems, it's sometimes obvious and natural what independence assumptions one might want to make, but here I don't see any natural assumptions. Do you?

Comment: Let's assume the following scenario: Earlier this morning, a perfectly uniformly random sheep has roamed themself into your room. Your dad hasn't seen it, just heard through the door closed by draught. So your dad doesn't know what kind of sheep this is. He felt lazy about cleaning the sheep's pen so he came up with the idea of making the bet with you. He locked the sheep and hid the key. You sneakily managed to peep through the key hole and establish the sheep is a black lamb. You're not able to establish the sheep's gender (who would, peeping through a key hole).

Comment: So the sheep is "perfectly random" and the information you hold is completely accidental. The paradox I can see here is: If 80% of the black sheep were male and I only knew the sheep is black I would bet for male without second thoughts. If 20% of the lambs were male and I exclusively knew the sheep is a lamb, I would bet for a female. And I think in both cases my bet would be "mathematically justified". But what if we hold both pieces of information at the same time? Isn't there a mathematically justified bet we can make in this situation?

Comment: @Ismael: Nice story :-) Were some lambs slaughtered? It used to be that $40\%$ of them were male...